# Regex, must contain a number, 1-5 chars and letters and digits

Tags: regex

Specs:

- 1 - 5 chars length
- Contains at least 1 number char
- Only A-Z, a-z and 0-9 allowed

This is what I have sofar: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,5}$`

Problem I have this accepts `'AV'` for example. It must contain a number to be valid.

https://regex101.com/r/i5VnXt/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a positive lookahead `(?=\D*\d)` and use `{1,5}` limiting quantifier at the end to match 1 to 5 chars:

```
^(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i5VnXt/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=\D*\d)` -  a positive lookahead requiring a digit after 0 or more non-digit symbols
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}` - 1 to 5 (due to `{1,5}` limiting quantifier) consecutive alphanumeric chars (ASCII letters or digits)
- `$` - end of string.